# When using "Bake from Multires", the resulting normal map has odd pattern along topology

Tags: cycles-render-engine, modifiers, texture-baking, normal-map, multiresolution

A very peculiar, corrugated pattern appears on the baked normal map from the Bake from Multires option.

Blendfile: https://pasteall.org/blend/53326714fd7e42ab966a58667ca05faf

Everything I've done:

1. 4k Resolution
2. Non-Color Data
3. 32-bit float
4. Smooth shaded geometry before applying the Multires modifier.

No matter how I rearrange the UV, it's the same strange result. From top to bottom in the images is the high poly, low poly, the baked normal map, the low poly with the normal map applied, and the weird pattern moving along the topology.

[image: The high poly sculpt]

[image: The low poly]

[image: The odd normal map baked from multires]

[image: The odd normal map applied to the low poly]

[image: The weird pattern along the topology]

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue. I know it's months late but I was able to figure it out. In the multires modifier there's an "apply base" option that conforms the base to match the sculpt. This fixed the issue for me.